# Jquery background change not working as intended

Tags: jquery

I have two while loops one within the other. In the second loop I hide the tr containing some info and when I click on the button with a class of 'toggle' I change the css display and also the background of the tr where the button is in.

All is good except for when I click the button it changes all the tr's (with class="display" backrounds following the one I have chosen where it's only to change the tr the button is in.

I'm working with unique ID's so I have no idea why it's changing all the tr's

```
while($myrow = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$content .= <<<EOF_
<tr id="cur{$myrow[inv]}" style="background-color:#e6f0ff">
<td height="25"></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td><input id="but{$myrow[inv]}" class="toggle" style="width:50px" type="button" value="+"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="display" id="tr{$myrow[inv]}" style="display:none"><td colspan="6">
<table>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td><td></td>
</tr>
EOF_;
$sql_det = "SELECT * FROM `deliveries` WHERE `inv`='$myrow[inv]' ORDER BY `app_number`";
$result_det = $mysqli->query($sql_det);
while($myrow_det = $result_det->fetch_assoc()){
$content .= <<<EOF_
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
EOF_;
}
$content .= <<<EOF_
</table></td></tr>
EOF_;
}
$content .= <<<EOF_
```

My Jquery:

```
$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').attr('id');
var current = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    if($(this).val() == '-'){
        $(this).val('+')
        $('#'+current).css('background-color','#e6f0ff');
        $('#'+row).css('display', 'none');
   }
   else if($(this).val() == '+'){
       $(this).val('-');
       $('#'+current).css('background-color','#d1e2fb');
       $('#'+row).css('display', '');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix is as below

Replace

```
var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').attr('id');
var current = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

with

```
var row = $(this).parent().parent().next('tr').attr('id');
var current = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both my method and yours work in getting the correct id's. The part I'm struggeling with is that it's not just changing the tr's backround I want it to, but also all the tr's following in the loop and that's the part I can not figure out. As soon as a new tr is created in the loop the tr gets a new id so I can not understand why that row's background also change.

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to get the `id` of the `current` and `next` row and then create a id selector again to change their styles, rather just point to target elements and add css styles. like below

always use `===` for strict comparison as you are not comparing string literals  directly.

```
 $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
  var current = $(this).closest('tr');
  if($(this).val() === '-'){
    $(this).val('+')
    $(current).css('background-color','#e6f0ff');
    $(row).css('display', 'none');
 }
 else if($(this).val() === '+'){
   $(this).val('-');
   $(current).css('background-color','#d1e2fb');
   $(row).css('display', '');
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use the code like you indicated nothing works.. I need to indicate that it is an id I'm working with thus have to use the $('#'+row) before the code works.

Comment: Could you create  a jsfiddle and replicate ur issue there,it will be easy to fix it. http://jsfiddle.net